# Is it possible to integrate Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration library with ASP.NET 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I decided to migrate one of my ASP.NET MVC 5 applications to ASP.NET Core 2, but I would like to keep both versions working. I've already migrated all class libraries to .NET Standard (so that I can use them in both projects) and wanted to use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration standard library to manage app settings.

Although using this configuration library in ASP.NET Core 2.0 is not a problem, I couldn't find a way to correctly load web.config file in ASP.NET MVC 5 app. This is my current code used for loading the web.config file:

```
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.AddXmlFile("web.config");

_configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
```

However, every time I run the application, I receive exception: `System.FormatException: A duplicate key 'appSettings:add:key' was found'appSettings:add:key'`. I double checked the file and there is no duplicate key, so I guess it's a problem with compatibility. Did anybody use the MS Configuration library with ASP.NET MVC 5 and found a way to properly use stadnard web.config file with it?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Temporarily, I created some ugly solution and then I decided to give up on the MVC 5 project so there was no need to fix this. However, you can check the answer provided here: https://benfoster.io/blog/net-core-configuration-legacy-projects/ . `LegacyConfigurationProvider` mentioned in the last section looks like the solution that could make it work

Comment: No worries. Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 0):

Some keys now defined on higher level and you need to avoid duplication of it inside configuration.

For example I had same errors in loading until I removed keys:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, even after removing the default keys, exception is thrown for my custom app settings which are used in the application. Moreover, even after removing all app.settings, another exception started to be thrown at line which starts `<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">` section. The exception states that 'XML namespaces are not supported asp.net web.config'